# Cookies vs Access Token for API security

Tags: security, cookies, access-token, api-design

I'm designing an API and so looking for solution to secure it.
I came across this article: https://github.com/alexbilbie/alexbilbie.github.com/blob/master/_posts/2014-11-11-oauth-and-javascript.md

which is old but I think it's still relevant. However there's something I don't really understand, as I'm still new to this.

In the article that guy wrote that instead saving and using access tokens to call directly API from the client-side (which is not secure since there's no way to well protect the access token), he set up a proxy which holds the tokens, and then issue an encrypted cookies for client-side.

I don't really see why it is more secure this way. In both case once the attacker steal the access token or the cookie, it's done. Isn't it ?

Am I missing something ?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

There's not really a benefit too having a proxy act as the Relying Party and hiding the access tokens in there.

Even if the proxy issues encrypted cookies to the client, those cookies are still linked to a domain and sent with any request made to that domain. So if the user has a malicious application running in their browser and that app makes a call to a protected API, it will be able to piggy-back off the cookie set when logging into the legitimate app.

(This is even more of a problem for apps that have long sessions that last hours or days or more.)

The only minor benefits I see from this approach are:

- It allows you to start building OAuth2/OIDC-compliant APIs on the server side rather than using cookie-based authentication, so can help in migration / uplift scenarios in complex environments.
- The cookie approach can be used with third-party apps or libraries that for whatever reason can't support OAuth2/OIDC. (But maybe you should stay away from these if they can't be properly secured.)

If you want to protect the access token on the client, I'd suggest one of the more secure approaches would be storing it as a variable within your app (i.e. in memory) and NOT persisting it to local or session storage. This stops it being accessed by JavaScript by another app, and you're in complete control of when the access token gets submitted to the API, unlike a cookie which is handled transparently by the browser.